# What is the Heroku equivalent for Django applications?

Tags: python, django, heroku

What is the Heroku equivalent for Django applications? (Edit: Question not relevant anymore as Heroku now supports Django)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to answer this for future reference, Heroku supports python and Django. See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/language-support) for documentation on what languages is supported by Heroku.

Comment: I highly recommend not starting on Heroku.   THey have constant changes that will break you apps without warning.  Not worth it.

Answer (score 4):

There are, however, alternatives to Heroku which you might want to look into:

https://www.ep.io/

https://gondor.io/

Both are run by pretty influential people in the Django community.

Answer (score 1):

You can`Openshift` to deploy your Django applications.

Here is the link to it : https://openshift.redhat.com/app/